# Mobius band gluing construction

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, mobius-band

Can somebody help me understand how the mobius band can be viewed as $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]/\sim$ where $(x,y)\sim (x+1,1-y)$?

(also, if somebody can help me with the appropriate tags)

Comment: Do you believe that $[0,1]\times[0,1]/\sim$ is a Mobius band? This corresponds to taking a strip of paper, giving it a half-twist, and gluing the ends together. The only difference is that you have $\mathbb{R} \times[0,1]/\sim$, so the strip of paper keeps wrapping around the Mobius band infinitely many times.

Comment: @kccu: I think your comment would make a nice answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is $y-1$ and not $1-y$?

Comment: you're right- it has been changed